# How do I wait for axios get to be returned?

Tags: javascript, html, async-await, axios

When I console.log the array in the finally block within the get(), not all the values that are suppose to be retrieved by the helper() isn't there. I imagine this is because of the axios method is asynchronous. I thought that if I used the await keyword on the helper() it would wait on the method so that all the values I wanted could be printed but that doesnt happen. Is there a way I can wait on the helper method?

```
(function get() {
    let videoThumbnails = new Array();
    axios.get(urlConstants.latestAnimeUrl)
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                const html = res.data;
                const $ = cheerio.load(html);
                const thumbnails = $(".post div a img");
                for (let i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
                    let videoThumbnail = new Object;
                    videoThumbnail.thumbnailLink = thumbnails[i].attribs['data-cfsrc']; //image thumbnail link, thumbnail dimensions if needed
                    videoThumbnails.push(videoThumbnail);
                }
                const links = $("a[itemprop=url]")
                links.each(async function (i, elem) {
                    if (i < thumbnails.length) {
                        videoThumbnails[i].thumbnailTitle = $(this).attr("title");
                        await helper($(this).attr("href").toString(),videoThumbnails,i);// link to video webpage, but need actual video link

                    }
                });
            }

        })
        .finally(() => {
            console.log(videoThumbnails);
        });
    return videoThumbnails;
})();

function helper(chiaUrl,videoThumbnails,index) {
     axios.get(chiaUrl)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
                const videoLink = $("div[id=load_anime] div iframe");
                videoThumbnails[index].thumbnailLink = videoLink.attr("src");    
            }
        })
        .finally(()=> {

        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`axios.get` returns a promise. The promise can be chained and awaited.
Your `helper` function returns `undefined`. You should return the result of the `axios.get`

```js
function helper(chiaUrl,videoThumbnails,index) {
     return axios.get(chiaUrl)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
                const videoLink = $("div[id=load_anime] div iframe");
                videoThumbnails[index].thumbnailLink = videoLink.attr("src");    
            }
        })
        .finally(()=> {

        })
}
```

It's also worth noting that if you return something within the `.then`, it will be the result of the await (so that you don't have to pass in `videoThumbnails` and mutate it to get the result).